# Php function 301 redirect

Tags: functions, wp-redirect

I am using this code so that when the user visits the old permalink, he gets redirected to the new one.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_external_url' );
function redirect_to_external_url() {
    if ( is_page( 'https://www.domain.com/brands/haute-couture/' ) ) {
      wp_redirect( 'https://www.domain.com/brands/fashion/', 301 ); 
    exit;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I am also using Nginx. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the question. I needed to redirect all posts of my wordpress site into a new NUXT frontend website. Pasted into the custom plugin I made, and it just works!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with `wp_redirect` part of your code...

But... `is_page` function can’t be used with URL address... You should pass “Page ID, title, slug, or array of such” as stated in [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/).

Comment: so how could i test if the slug is "brands/haute-couture/" ?

Comment: Test for slug or post ID (testing for post ID is best - most reliable)

Comment: But if a user finds this page on google: https://www.domain.com/brands/haute-couture/ - will this be associated with the post ID by wordpress and be redirected ?

Comment: Yes - all posts have their IDs assigned - if the post is displayed, then you have access to all its properties.